# MacBook Air fans on 100% with Boot Camp running Windows 10

Tags: macos, mac, cpu, boot-camp, fan

I installed Windows 10 via Bootcamp on my 2015 MacBook Air and it doesn't seem to include a cooling management: the fan is running on 6500 rpm (100%) all the time, even when the CPU is below 10% usage.

I installed `Macs Fan Control`, a software for OS X and Windows that allows you to make the Mac fans run more dynamically based on the temperature of sensors on the board. I used the standard settings and it brought down the noise **a lot**. However, it's still spinning at about 3000 rpm (even when the CPU is below 10%) and I am a bit afraid of melting my Mac if the software messes up something. The MacBook should theoretically turn off when it's getting too hot but I don't want to risk anything with that $2000 machine. You can only make the software read from one of the sensors which means while one could looks "a bit warm", the other one could be dying.

Also, 3000 RPM on idle with that `Macs Fan Control` software is better than 6500 RPM but it isn't exactly "good" regarding the fact that while using OS X I usually have 40% of that (1200 RPM).

Googling this problem I can only find threads from YEARS ago so I suppose that this shouldn't be an issue as Boot Camp somehow takes care of that but it definitely does not work well for me.

Is there something I missed?

Answer (score 0):

I rebooted two times, deactivated `Macs Fan Control` and suddenly the fan was running on 1200-1400 RPM and only got faster when I actually performed CPU-heavy tasks. It seems like Windows needed a (or two) reboot(s) to make the fan go the way it should do. It's still a bit worse than running macOS but wayyy better than it was before.

Also, thanks to the one who downvoted my question, that was really helpful!

Answer (score -1):

You can adjust the power settings in the control panel to control the fan speed.

[Adjust Windows Power Settings to Reduce Fan Noise](https://youtu.be/crzJw2oYl_8)